# does latest version of Visio support vba changing org chart subordinate layout

Tags: vba, visio

I have seen some references to being able to change the subordinate layout via vba using something like the following.  Is there a way to change subordinate layout's programmatically via VBA with the latest version of Visio?

Thanks

Brady

Call Visio.Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run("/toolbar_vert")

ChatGPT also said the following:

To change the layout of subordinates in Visio using VBA, you can use the Layout property of the Shape object. Here is an example code snippet that demonstrates how to change the layout of subordinates in a Visio organization chart:

```
vbnetCopy codeSub ChangeSubordinateLayout()
    Dim orgChart As Visio.Document
    Set orgChart = Application.ActiveDocument

    Dim orgChartPage As Visio.Page
    Set orgChartPage = orgChart.Pages(1)

    Dim orgChartShapes As Visio.Shapes
    Set orgChartShapes = orgChartPage.Shapes

    Dim topLevelShape As Visio.Shape
    Set topLevelShape = orgChartShapes.ItemFromID(1)

    Dim subordinates As Visio.Shapes
    Set subordinates = topLevelShape.Subordinates

    Dim subordinateShape As Visio.Shape
    For Each subordinateShape In subordinates
        subordinateShape.Layout = VisLayoutTypes.visLORL
    Next subordinateShape
End Sub
```

This code assumes that you have an organization chart on the first page of the active Visio document, and that the top-level shape has an ID of 1. The code loops through each subordinate shape and sets its layout to visLORL, which is a layout that arranges the subordinates in a horizontal tree-like structure. You can replace visLORL with any other valid VisLayoutTypes enumeration value to use a different layout.

Call Visio.Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run("/toolbar_vert")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about ChatGPT generated code

Comment: ChatGPT content is not allowed on SO.  Please dwlete this post.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with VBA, but I wouldn't go as far as to call it "supported" since this is done using addons included with Visio that (as far as I can tell) don't have official documentation and could change or be removed from one version to the next.

From what I've seen the org chart shapes are also quite unusual compared to regular shapes, and have many quirks. For example, a lot of the properties related to layout  and shape type are read only / don't change the shape visibly if changed in the shapesheet or via VBA.

That being said, there's two methods I've found to do this using Visio 2016, and the shape must also be selected for either of these to work.

1. calling the "orgC11" addon with one of the arguments to arrange subordinates

   This can be done with the line
   `Application.Addons("OrgC11").Run(argument)`, and the OrgC11 arguments for arranging subordinates that I'm aware of are listed here:

   ```
   "/gallery_horiz1", "/gallery_horiz2", "/gallery_horiz3", "/gallery_horiz4", "/gallery_horiz5", "/gallery_horiz6"

   "/gallery_vert1", "/gallery_vert2", "/gallery_vert3", "/gallery_vert4", "/gallery_vert5", "/gallery_vert6", "/gallery_vert7", "/gallery_vert8"

   "/gallery_sidebyside1", "/gallery_sidebyside2", "/gallery_sidebyside3", "/gallery_sidebyside4"
   ```
2. calling the "arrange subordinates" dialog using an org chart shape's ShapeSheet, then using SendKeys() to navigate to and select the desired layout using the arrow, tab, and enter keys.

   This should actually be done in the reverse order since SendKeys puts the commanded keypresses into a queue for execution, so that would look something like this:

```
    Sub arrangeSubordinates(shp As Visio.Shape, Optional rearIdx As Integer = -1)
    ' rearIdx: offset number relative to the last menu item; Default is double side-by-side, horizontal is rearIdx=17
    ' 11-> vertical #1, 8-> side-by-side #1
    Dim keysToSend
    keysToSend = Replace(Space(17), " ", "{DOWN}") 'Move to last menu item for a point of reference
    If shp Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "Module1.arrangeSubordinates", _
        "shp is None! Not allowed!"
    End If
    If shp.CellExists("Actions.ArrangeSubs.Action", 0) Then    'this Action field seems to only exist on org chart shapes
        If shp.SectionExists(visSectionAction, 0) Then
            If rearIdx > 0 Then
                keysToSend = keysToSend & Replace(Space(rearIdx), " ", "{UP}") 'Move to another menu item from the last menu item
            End If
            keysToSend = keysToSend & "{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}"  'Confirm layout selection
            Debug.Print ("Pre-Dialog " & Left(shp.Text, InStr(1, shp.Text, vbLf)))
            SendKeys (keysToSend)
            shp.CellsU("Actions.ArrangeSubs.Action").Trigger    'Run dialog with queued keys
            Debug.Print ("Post-Dialog")
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

original source for OrgC11 arguments: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4286.msg16731#msg16731